# Combining two (applescript) scripts into one

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to simplify my workflow by combining the following two applescripts into one, they work fine separately but it'd be more efficient to combine them.
In short, script A trims a file name into the last 3 characters and Script B adds the folder name (where the files reside) to the file name.
This might be a very simple fix but I'm script-writing challenged so any help is welcomed.

**SCRIPT A:**

```
on open whichFile
  repeat with aFile in whichFile
    tell application "Finder"
      set filename to name of aFile
      set name of aFile to ((characters -1 thru -7 of filename) as string)
      --set name of whichFile to ((characters 1 thru -4 of filename) as string) --trim last 3
    end tell
  end repeat
end open
```

**SCRIPT B**

```
on open theDroppedItems
  repeat with a from 1 to length of theDroppedItems
    set theCurrentDroppedItem to item a of theDroppedItems
    set theCurrentDroppedItem to theCurrentDroppedItem as string
    tell application "System Events"
      set folderPath to theCurrentDroppedItem as string
      --display dialog (folderPath)
      set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
      set newFileName to (text item -4 of folderPath as string) & "-" & (text item -2 of folderPath as string) & "-" & (text item -1 of folderPath as string)
      --display dialog (newFileName)
      --rename file
      set fileAlias to (theCurrentDroppedItem) as alias
      set the name of fileAlias to newFileName
    end tell
  end repeat
end open
```

Comment: The file name includes the extension - are you assuming a particular extension or name length?

Comment: @ red_menace - only the filename changes, the extension remains as is. thanks

Comment: Do not cross-post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange websites. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368306/combining-two-scripts

Comment: I thought I saw that somewhere before...

Answer (score 0):

You can start by opening a new **Script Editor** document for the combined script.  The `open` handler is passed a list of file items, so you can add a new handler declaration with an empty `repeat` statement that steps through the dropped items.  From there, just identify the statements that perform the various operations (trim name, get folder name, etc), and copy them into the new `open` handler's `repeat` statement, editing as needed to use consistent variable names.

Once the new script is running, then you can look at optimizing it by combining and/or rearranging statements that may be doing the same thing in the different scripts.  It can also be helpful to organize functions into their own handlers, such as the `getNamePieces` handler below.  I also like to add a `run` handler with a `choose file` dialog so that you can test without having to drag items onto a droplet.

Note that the file name includes any extension, so you should break it apart in order to work with just the name part.  There is also a bit of unnecessary thrashing about in the script that gets the folder name, so after cleaning it up your script could look something like:

```
on run
    open (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
end run

on open droppedItems
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        set {folderPath, theName, extension} to getNamePieces from anItem
        set trimmedName to text -1 thru -3 of theName -- work with just the name part
        tell application "System Events"
            set folderName to name of disk item folderPath 
            set newName to folderName & "-" & trimmedName & extension -- assemble the pieces
            log newName -- for testing
            # set name of anItem to newName -- uncomment to go live
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

to getNamePieces from someItem -- return the containing folder path, the name, and the extension
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (someItem as text)
        set theContainer to path of the container
        set {theName, extension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if extension is not "" then
        set theName to text 1 thru -((count extension) + 2) of theName -- just the name part
        set extension to "." & extension
    end if
    return {theContainer, theName, extension}
end getNamePieces
```